# How to preserved the CardView (wrap by LinearLayout) elevation, without using margin or cardUseCompatPadding?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I have the following xml layout that has two card views

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.elye.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/card_layout"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <include layout="@layout/card_layout"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The card view is as simple as

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_new_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="MY TEXT"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My image as below. This is not good as the elevation of the second card is missing.

[image]

As I wanted the elevation in my second card view as well, so I add `android:layout_margin="10dp"` for my cardView as below. Note the 10dp to make this clearer that the size of both cardview now differs.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_new_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="MY TEXT"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Now the view look like below. Which is not good. My second card shrink.

[image]

So now I remove the `android:layout_margin="10dp"` with `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`. And the view as below.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_new_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="MY TEXT"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This now have the elevation on both and consistent is size. But then it had an extreme in huge gap between the two cardview, which is not good for me. I want my original gap... as per the picture at the bottom.

[image]

Ideally I wanted something look like below, together with the second cardView is still wrap by something (in this case a LinearLayout). The margin, and cardUseCompatPadding is not solving my problem.

So my question is, how to preserved the CardView (wrap by LinearLayout) elevation, without using margin or cardUseCompatPadding, and still look the same as CardView by purely include only. (i.e. the first cardview of my diagram)

P/S: Don't ask me to remove the LinearLayout, as it is used as illustration. I need that wrapper for other reason (i.e. dynamic change the view within)

[image]

Comment: it looks like the method using cardUseCompatPadding is pretty good. Could you not compensate for that extra margin on the top by playing around with the margins of the linear layout? Or even use a negative translationY on that linear layout?

Comment: Thanks. I could do that, but I'm shock to know that `cardUseCompatPadding` is making extra gap, that is much more than the padding/margin stated. Where did those gap come from? Can it be prevented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this will help you.

This is your first code, I have added width and height for 2nd include tag.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="com.example.elye.myapplication.MainActivity">

            <include
                layout="@layout/card_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/card_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!--<include-->
                <!--layout="@layout/card_layout"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_margin="16dp" />-->
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

and cardview layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_new_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="MY TEXT" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Activity.java

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);
        try {
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.card_layout);
            final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
            View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.card_layout, null);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            int x = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin_16);
            params.setMargins(x, x, x, x);
            view.setLayoutParams(params);
            linearLayout.addView(view);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In res/values/dimens.xml add following line

```
 <dimen name="margin_16">16dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Great. This seems to work. I wonder if we could do this dynamically... the reason I need the LinearLayout externally, as I intend to add my cardview dynamically. But then the "include" is hard to add. I could only add the cardView... Is there a way to have the "include" with added dynamically (i.e. programmatically) together with the height/width and margin as what you did?

Comment: P/S: I still give a tick and upvote to your answer as it answer my question above, even though I don't know if my issue is solve (i.e. need to do this dynamically)... So if you have any idea of my question on the comment above, would be great. Thank you!!

Comment: @Elye I have updated my code above. Please check it. I guess this will help you.